# Want to build an online webmail script

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, webmail

I want to build an online webmail script, that only works for the users of the system, so u can call it a privat message system aswell.

But before i start, then im need some info/feedback.
The database layout. how will that look like, is there some roles for that.

and is there a database layout out there, so i can get some ideas how to build up the database !?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: i have these tables
Users
ID.....

SentMessages
MessageID Auto/Key
Subject
MessageText
MessageDateTime
SenderUserID
ReceiverUserID
IsRead Yes/No

ReceivedMessages
MessageID Auto/Key
Subject
MessageText
MessageDateTime
SenderUserID
ReceiverUserID
IsRead Yes/No

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not create both Sent and Received Messages in different tables, just create one table Messages, as you would other wise create duplicate data, no? (Sender and receiver are in the same messaging system).

When you need to collect the messages for a certain receiver, just query on receiverUserId instead of querying on the received messages table.